# Making divs visible and invisible with 1 button without JQUERYand an error if not correctly filled in textfields

Tags: javascript

Im working on a little project.

Here is the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/GJf46/

I need the invisible button to make all three divs invisible when clicked and visible again when clicked.
I tried doing this:

```
var gone = document.getElementById("invisible");
var div1 = document.getElementById("one");
var div2 = document.getElementById("two");
var div3 = document.getElementById("three");
gone.addEventListener("click", function () {
    if (
    div1.style.visibility == "visible",
    div2.style.visibility == "visible",
    div3.style.visibility == "visible") {
        div1.style.visibility == "hidden";
        div2.style.visibility == "hidden";
        div3.style.visibility == "hidden";
    } else {
        div1.style.visibility == "visible";
        div2.style.visibility == "visible";
        div3.style.visibility == "visible";
    }
});
```

Also I need an alert box when the textfields are not filled in correctly.
It should only accept the values I set as an example.
But I got no clue how to do that, im new to javascript.

I want this all without JQUERY.

Comment: why are you using `==` for assignment in the `if` and `else` blocks?

Comment: there are plenty of answers based on your doubt,did you search first

Comment: use display none and block instead,visibility would occupy space on your page..

Comment: "I want this all without JQUERY" - I want a cheeseburger, can someone get me one please

Comment: look this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GJf46/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You accidentally wrote == (equality comparison) instead of = (assignment). The corrected code can be tested [here](http://jsfiddle.net/GJf46/5/).

```
weg.addEventListener("click", function () {
    if (
    div1.style.visibility !== "hidden",
    div2.style.visibility !== "hidden",
    div3.style.visibility !== "hidden") {
        div1.style.visibility = "hidden";
        div2.style.visibility = "hidden";
        div3.style.visibility = "hidden";
    } else {
        div1.style.visibility = "";
        div2.style.visibility = "";
        div3.style.visibility = "";
    }
});
```

I utilized the fact that the default `visibility` is `"visible"` ([source](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_visibility.asp)). Note that I explicitly check whether the `visibility` is `"hidden"`. This is important: the `visibility` is an empty string initially, so testing whether it is `"visible"` leads to that the button doesn't work the first time it is clicked. One could solve this by writing `div1.style.visibility === "visible" || div1.style.visibility === ""` etc., but the above version is shorter.

---

The code can be made a bit cleaner if you introduce a state variable (the test is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/GJf46/6/)):

```
var divsAreVisible = true;
weg.addEventListener("click", function () {
    if (divsAreVisible) {
        div1.style.visibility = "hidden";
        div2.style.visibility = "hidden";
        div3.style.visibility = "hidden";
    } else {
        div1.style.visibility = "";
        div2.style.visibility = "";
        div3.style.visibility = "";
    }
    divsAreVisible = !divsAreVisible;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
div1.style.visibility = "visible";
div2.style.visibility = "visible";
div3.style.visibility = "visible";
```

And so on.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to

```
var gone = document.getElementById("invisible");
var div1 = document.getElementById("one");
var div2 = document.getElementById("two");
var div3 = document.getElementById("three");
gone.addEventListener("click", function (){
    if (
    div1.style.visibility == "visible",
    div2.style.visibility == "visible",
    div3.style.visibility == "visible"
    ){
            div1.style.visibility = "hidden";
            div2.style.visibility = "hidden";
            div3.style.visibility = "hidden";
} else {
    div1.style.visibility == "visible";
    div2.style.visibility == "visible";
    div3.style.visibility == "visible";
}
});
```

And it should work :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
gone.addEventListener("click", clickToggle);

function clickToggle() {
    var value = clickToggle.blnVisible ? "visible" : "hidden";
    div1.style.visibility = value;
    div2.style.visibility = value;
    div3.style.visibility = value;
    clickToggle.blnVisible = (value == "hidden");
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DkGWn/1/)** (*sample*)

Comment: I am a bit confused, can `==` be used to assign a value?

Comment: @Harry yup. try it in console and check.

Comment: @Harry ohh cheez.. I was using `==` operator inside the code. :D Updated thanks.

Comment: @Harry I was actually thinking that your comment is about assigning something like this: `value == "visible"` (_last line_). I misunderstood your comment.